# How to get the Thread trace during reading a File

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have File and I want to do the following task: (just to get more knowledge about the thread reading and writing file.)

When an application starts andthe  file is read  I want to have information about all the streams which are open and how many threads are reading from the same stream.

Is there a way I can have all the stream information via reflection . Is there another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest some sort of `StreamFactory` class that will maintain that information for you.  Threads can then do a `InputStream getStream(File)` and `closeStream(InputStream)` or some such and the factory will maintain the list of which thread has what streams open and provide some statistics functions such as:

```
public Collection<InputStream> getOpenStreams()
```

and

```
public int getNumThreadsWithStream(InputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something you have to keep track of yourself.  If you are sharing a file stream between threads (and I suggest you don't do this, use one thread for reading the stream and pass work to a thread pool if you need too.) you can keep track of all the Thread which have attempted to read the stream.